# Promise.All promise parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've got two promises, each returning an array of strings. I run them with `Promise.all(p1, p2)` but I am surprised the values parameter it resolves to is an array of 12k strings (which would be one of the both promises' returns).

```
const p1 = ModelA.find()
  .then((bandProfiles) => {
    const bandProfilePlayerTags = []
    // [...] Filling this array with strings
    return bandProfilePlayerTags
  })

const p2 = ModelB.find()
  .then((response) => {
    const playerTags = []
    // [...] Filling this array with strings
    return playerTags
  })

Promise.all(p1, p2).then((values) => {
  // Values is an array containing more than 12k strings
})
```

I expected that values is an array of length 2. `values[0]` would be the returned array from promise 1 and `values[1]` is the returned array from promise 2. What am I missing here?

Comment: Oh god, I am used to build promiseArrays and pass this as parameter. What a dumb mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try passing p1 and p2 in an array like

```
const p1 = ModelA.find()
  .then((bandProfiles) => {
    const bandProfilePlayerTags = []
    // [...] Filling this array with strings
    return bandProfilePlayerTags
  })

const p2 = ModelB.find()
  .then((response) => {
    const playerTags = []
    // [...] Filling this array with strings
    return playerTags
  })

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((values) => {
  // Values is an array containing more than 12k strings
})
```

> Promise.all(iterable); expects an iterable object as a parameter

Answer (score 4):

You did pass (a promise for) an array of 12k strings to `Promise.all`, not an array of two promises. You'll want to use

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => …)
//          ^      ^
```